# c programming dynamic allocation of struct pointers

Tags: c, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation, realloc

The program reads the input '1z' as (str+0)->input_name, '2y' as (str+1)->input_name, and '3x' as (str+2)->input_name. Now what i want to do is to insert a new string to (str+0)->input_name without eliminating the initial elements. So initial (str+0)->input_name would become (str+1)->input_name, (str+1)->input_name becomes (str+2)->input_name, and (str+2)->input_name becomes (str+3)->input_name. How would i do this??

**Initialize items**

Number of products: 3

Enter name: 1z

Enter name: 2y

Enter name: 3x

**Output**

1 -> 1z

2 -> 2y

3 -> 3x

=====================

Input: 4a

**Output**

1 -> 4a

2 -> 2y

3 -> 3x

4 -> Hello

What i want to do is:

**Output**

1 -> 4a

2 -> 1z

3 -> 2y

4 -> 3x

What should i do?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 1000

struct input{
  char input_name[SIZE];
};

int main(){    
  int i, startNum;
  struct input *str;
  char _startNum[SIZE];
  char _mode[SIZE];

  fputs("****Choose Menu****\n", stderr);    
  fputs("\n**Initialize items**\nNumber of products: ", stderr);
  fgets(_startNum, SIZE, stdin);
  startNum = atoi(_startNum);

  str = (struct input*)malloc(startNum * sizeof(struct input));
  if (str == NULL){
    printf("Memory allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < startNum; i++){
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets((str+i)->input_name, sizeof(struct input), stdin);
  }
  printf("\n");


  fputs("\n**Output**\n", stderr);  
  for(i = 0; i < startNum; i++){
    printf("%d -> %s", i+1, (str+i)->input_name);
  }
  printf("\n");

  startNum++;

  strcpy((str+startNum-1)->input_name, "Hello");
  for(i = startNum - 1; i = 0; i--){
    strcpy((str+i)->input_name,(str+i-1)->input_name);
  }

  fputs("Input: ", stderr); 
  fgets((str+0)->input_name, SIZE, stdin);

  fputs("\n**Output**\n", stderr);  
  for(i = 0; i < startNum; i++){
    printf("%d -> %s", i+1, (str+i)->input_name);
  }
  fputs("\n", stderr);

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: You might like to read this: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: Use `perror` -not just a `printf`- on failure (e.g. of `malloc` ....)

Comment: thank you for helping, alk and Basile Starynkevitch!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I have understood correctly then you need the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define SIZE 1000

struct input{
  char input_name[SIZE];
};

int main( void )
{    
  int i, startNum;
  struct input *str;
  char _startNum[SIZE];
  char _mode[SIZE];

  fputs("****Choose Menu****\n", stderr);    
  fputs("\n**Initialize items**\nNumber of products: ", stderr);
  fgets(_startNum, SIZE, stdin);
  startNum = atoi(_startNum);

  str = (struct input*)malloc(startNum * sizeof(struct input));
  if (str == NULL){
    printf("Memory allocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  for(i = 0; i < startNum; i++){
    printf("Enter name: ");
    fgets((str+i)->input_name, SIZE, stdin);
  }
  printf("\n");


  fputs("\n**Output**\n", stderr);  
  for(i = 0; i < startNum; i++){
    printf("%d -> %s", i+1, (str+i)->input_name);
  }
  printf("\n");

  startNum++;


  struct input tmp =  realloc(str, startNum * sizeof(struct input));
  if (tmp == NULL){
    printf("Memory reallocation error\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }

  str = tmp;

  strcpy((str+startNum-1)->input_name, "Hello");
  for(i = startNum - 1; i != 0; i--){
    strcpy((str+i)->input_name,(str+i-1)->input_name);
  }

  fputs("Input: ", stderr); 
  fgets((str+0)->input_name, SIZE, stdin);

  fputs("\n**Output**\n", stderr);  
  for(i = 0; i < startNum; i++){
    printf("%d -> %s", i+1, (str+i)->input_name);
  }
  fputs("\n", stderr);

  free( str );

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

As for your code then it has undefined behavior because there was not allocated memory for the appended element.

And there is a typo in this loop

```
for(i = startNum - 1; i = 0; i--){
                      ^^^^^
```

where instead of comparison there is used assignment.

Also instead of this call

```
fgets((str+i)->input_name, sizeof(struct input), stdin);
```

in general you have to use

```
fgets((str+i)->input_name, sizeof((str+i)->input_name), stdin);
```

or

```
fgets((str+i)->input_name, SIZE, stdin);
```

Comment: Thank you Vlad! I got some errors as followed: (44)error c2440 '=' cannot convert from 'void *' to 'input', (45)error C2676: binary '==' : 'input' does not define this operator, (50)error c2440 '=' cannot convert from 'input' to 'input*'.

Line (44) is the line you defined tmp with realloc. I am not sure how can i fixed this. Do you have any idea?

Comment: This worked after i changed the line to:

  struct input *tmp;
  tmp = (struct input*)realloc(str, startNum * sizeof(struct input));

Thank you very much Vlad!!